# How can i make a template cross browser compatible?

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

---

I have a very normal issue.But I couldn't find any answer.I made a simple PSD to HTML.I tried to make it cross-browser compatible.But I couldn't do it.So that's why I have a question.If I make a template in IE or Safari.Is it automatically compatible with all other browsers? Because `Safari` and `IE` are the worst browsers.Need suggestion from experts.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try some compiler like [prepros](https://prepros.io/) which'll automatically add browser prifixes

Answer (score 0):

most of css2 properties works correctly for all browsers but the real problem is in css3

so you can use each browser code

for example we need to use `tranisition` the code will be

```
-webkit-transition: all 0.3s linear; /*chrome and safari*/
-moz-transition: all 0.3s linear; /*firefox*/
-o-transition: all 0.3s linear; /*opera*/
-ms-transition: all 0.3s linear; /*internet explorer*/
-transition: all 0.3s linear; /*for all new versions of browsers*/
```